# Microsoft Access Update Statement with Inner Joins and Subqueries

Tags: ms-access, join

I am having a tough time figuring out how to do this update query. Basically I need to update a table named tblOpenJobs. It needs to be updated with the dbo_WorkOrders table with the Max Install date. But there is not direct relationship between those two tables you need to have the dbo_premise table between. Here is my query, what am I doing wrong?

```
     UPDATE tblOpenJobs 
     INNER JOIN (dbo_Premise INNER JOIN dbo_WorkOrders w (WHERE w.InstallDate IN 
     (SELECT MAX(InstallDate) FROM dbo_WorkOrders WHERE dbo_WorkOrders.PremiseKey = w.PremiseKey)) 
     ON (dbo_Premise.PremiseKey = w.PremiseKey) 
     ON tblOpenJobs.ServiceOrderNum = dbo_Premise.AccountNumber
     SET tblOpenJobs.InstallerID = w.InstallerID,
     tblOpenJobs.InstallDate= w.InstallDate,
     tblOpenJobs.New_Serial_num= w.NewSerial,
     tblOpenJobs.Old_Reading= w.OldRead;
```

Comment: Pasting your SQL into Vim suggests you have an open parenthesis at "`INNER JOIN (dbo_Premise`" unmatched by a closing `)`.  But what does Access tell you when you run that query?  Is there an error message?  Does Access complain *"operation must use an updateable query"* or is the error something else?

Answer (score 1):

I checked this in Access 2007 query window:
Your query seems neither Transact-SQL, neither Access, as the two have different syntax.

In Access, table aliasing must use the keyword AS, while Transact-SQL does not require:

```
UPDATE ((tblOpenJobs 
     INNER JOIN dbo_Premise
        ON tblOpenJobs.ServiceOrderNum = dbo_Premise.AccountNumber)
     INNER JOIN dbo_WorkOrders AS w 
        ON dbo_Premise.PremiseKey = w.PremiseKey)
     SET tblOpenJobs.InstallerID = w.InstallerID,
         tblOpenJobs.InstallDate = w.InstallDate,
         tblOpenJobs.New_Serial_num = w.NewSerial,
         tblOpenJobs.Old_Reading = w.OldRead
     WHERE (w.InstallDate IN 
              (SELECT MAX(InstallDate) 
               FROM dbo_WorkOrders
               WHERE dbo_WorkOrders.PremiseKey = w.PremiseKey))
```

This is correct in syntax, but I'm not sure it can update your data, as multi-table linked update is not easy in Access.